# How do you spawn a component from a class in UE4?

Tags: unreal-4

**Background**
I'm working on a shooter game at the moment and I'm trying to spawn an `Actor Component` for the weapon currently in use, in order to have less `Actors` to keep track of.
The problem with this is that I can't easily switch out components on the fly, without making a separate function for each weapon.

**Question**
Is there currently any way to spawn a component with blueprints from a class like you would do with an `Actor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may spawn an actor component and attach it to any given actor. The C++ version of this would be:

```
UActorComponent* SpawnedComponent = ConstructObject<UActorComponent>(UStaticMeshComponent::StaticClass(), this, TEXT("DynamicSpawnedMeshCompoent");
if(SpawnedComponent)
{
    SpawnedComponent->RegisterComponent();
    SpawnedComponent->AttachTo(GetRootComponent(), NAME_None);
}
```

this is a pointer to an Actor class (so your weapon). Now, the key code here is the ConstructObject template function. In Blueprints you would call ["Construct Object from Class"](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/BlueprintAPI/Game/ConstructObjectfromClass/index.html) using a class reference to the Component you would like to create. The outer would be a reference to the owning actor of the component (the Weapon for instance). With the return value you will cast it to the desired component.

Comment: I already know that it's possible to do in c++,  but is it possible in blueprint?

Comment: Follow the "Construct Object from Class" link it is the same thing as the C++ version of ConstructObject<>

Comment: It just tested it and it just gives me "Error Wrong class to spawn" for both actors and components. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Seems that this is a known issue. Here is the AnswerHub question related to this [link](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/348296/what-are-the-limitations-of-construct-object-from.html). Finally, if you have some C++ skills, you can always use the above mentioned code and create a blueprint Library Function for yourself.